# Is there a default icon in ios 7 for settings in a UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios

I am looking if an icon like this is standard.(http://bit.ly/SVyCU1)

Is the above image standard?

Comment: I've seen both a wrench and a gear icon in the navigation bar. I guess both will work.

Comment: They aren't standard in ios 7 are they? Ahhh that's what it's called, a gear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gear or a wrench icon in the navigation bar ring a big iOS6 bell for me. I can't recall having encountered those in iOS7. As far as I can tell iOS7 hardly uses icons in the navigation bar anymore in favor of text.

Then again, there hardly ever are settings inside an app. Most apps use an "Edit" state for in-app changes and everything else goes into to the actual settings app via settings bundle.